# Running same application throwing error in IIS express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I was running a project say **ProjectA** in visual studio 2015 and for some reason, I have created a *copy* of that project say **CopyProjectA**.While running that copied project, i.e 
**CopyProjectA** project it was showing an error

> Port number is in use

So for that, I changed the port number of **CopyProjectA**.

Now, while I run **CopyProjectA** it's now showing

> Unable To Launch IIS Web server.
>   Failed to register URL "https://localhost:portnumber/" for site "*CopyProjectA* or *Project_Name(1)* " application "/". Error description Cannot create a file when that file is already exist (0x800700b7)

Note:
    CopyProjectA or Project_Name(1) both are same
Please help me to fix this problem :)

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html Jexus Manager would report more information. When you copy the project, a second `applicationHost.config` is created, and it uses the same port as the original. Thus, merely change the project file won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a new virtual directory for the application after changing the port number; this will delete any related configuration caused by the old website.

From the Properties of your application;

[image]

Comment: no sir, while you change the port number and click on save button, it automatically creates virtual directory for us